# Simplifying eigenvalue calculation where only one non-zero element is shared by a row and column.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, block-matrices, characteristic-polynomial

I'm trying to determine the eigenvalues for the following matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Where the first row and column share a single non zero element (same happens for last row and column). Am I understanding correctly that this reduces to finding the eigenvalues of:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and of

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & -i & 0 \\
0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Or am I missing some key result on block matrices? Can you provide references as to how I can simplify computations of eigenvalues for large block matrices?

Comment: suggest you find the eigenvectors for $$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$ $$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$ $$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$     which can be padded with four zero entries  each to make eigenvectors for the original matrix

Comment: What is the theoretical justification in being able to do so?